# Why I can't assign a List Comprehensions to the list object inside it ?(Python)

Tags: python, list

After I write below code:

```
if isinstance(lst, (list, tuple)) and len(lst) > 0:
    lst = [v.lower() for v in lst]
    pv_on, uv_on = 'pv'in lst, 'uv' in lst
```

ouput error in PyCharm: `NameError: name 'lst' is not defined`

But if I use `lst2` instead 'lst' inside  `[v.lower() for v in lst]` as follow, it works fine.I just want to know why.

```
if isinstance(lst, (list, tuple)) and len(lst) > 0:
    lst2 = [v.lower() for v in lst]
    pv_on, uv_on = 'pv'in lst2, 'uv' in lst2
```

**Update:**
Maybe caused by decorator,
test code:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
def record_deco(lst):
    def _wrapper(func):
        def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):

            if isinstance(lst, (list, tuple)) and len(lst) > 0:
                lst = [v.lower() for v in lst]
                a_on, b_on = 'a' in lst, 'b' in lst
                print a_on
                print b_on
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return _wrapper

@record_deco(['a'])
def a(x):
    print x


a('xxx')
```

This time I use sublime,the ouput error is :`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lst' referenced before assignment`
And this error disappear after I change `lst` to `lst2`.

Comment: You probably have an error somewhere above this code, causing `lst` to not be defined in the first place. Perhaps a scope error? Did you create `lst` in a different function and expect the variable to be accessible outside the function?

Comment: Add a print statement right before the list comprehension. See what happens.

Comment: @user2357112 I find it happen when I use that in decorator.Sorry I put a wrong error msg,update just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign to a variable anywhere in a function, Python treats *all uses* of that variable in the function as local variables.  Since you assign to `lst` in `wrapper` it is treated as local to `wrapper`.  That means that when you do `lst = [v.lower() for v in lst]`, the local variable `lst` already needs to exist so it can be iterated over.  But no *local* variable `lst` exists, so an error is raised.  You can find dozens of other questions about this by searching Stackoverflow for UnboundLocalError.

The solution, as you already found, is to use a different name for your inner variable.  (In Python 3 you could use `nonlocal lst` to mark `lst` as being used from the enclosing `record_deco` function, but that wouldn't accomplish anything special here since you don't use `lst` except in the nested function.)

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lst = [v.lower() for v in lst]
a_on, b_on = 'a' in lst, 'b' in lst
a_on, b_on
(True, True)
```

Works for me. Puzzling.

Comment: I find it happen when I use that in decorator.